# GAE Django Transaction

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, transactions

I have been developing on the GAE dev_appserver and my code relied heavily on Django's transactionmiddleware. I have tested it locally and it works.

After deployment to GAE, however, model saves that are committed are not rolled back.

Sample code:

```
@transaction.commit_on_success
def get(self, request):
    name = request.GET.get('name')
    d = Department(name=name)
    d.save()
    raise Exception('Failed')
```

Is this because Django transaction API is not honored by GAE or is it a problem on my app settings?

FYI django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware is currently last on the list of MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES

Answer (score 1):

According to [this website](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine#queryset-methods), the Django database backend for Google App Engine does not support Django transactions. You can however use the `run_in_transaction` method from the App Engine's SDK.

Comment: I believe they are referring to their own package.

Comment: @beeftaco They're talking about [djangoappengine](https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangoappengine), as far as I know the only Django backend for Google App Engine.

Comment: I read about it more and it indeed is a third party thing and not part of GAE natively :(